# Openlayers 2.12 JSON layer color with TURF algorithms

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers, turfjs

I have different turf operations and now I want it some style. I have all the operations result in ee9900, that i think is the default colour of openlayers 2.12

So the think is I have a function that take the result and now I want it to put some style.

I created:

```
var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                    "ignoreExtraDims": true,
                });

var vector_layer   = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({
                });
```

I just simply added `vector_layer.style = {fillColor: 'red'};` and change the polygons features to red but in points and colours doesn't work.
Then I have:

```
vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(result.getData()));
legend.loadLayer(vector_layer);
```

Result is a variable that I have the result of different operation here. Then getData is a function to have the result.

Any idea what proceed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have it, I applied a style depending of the operation with Turf

```
vector_layer.style = {fillColor: "purple", pointRadius: 7, fillOpacity: 0.3, strokeColor:"#F2F2F2"};
```

But now I would like to set this like a default style because now it's not working the "style selection" button that I created with [Ext](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.picker.Color.html)